# ec2.create_fleet() is creating individual instances instead of a fleet and not respecting all the parameters I pass

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm using boto3 EC2.Client.create_fleet() to create a spot fleet request but I'm having trouble replicating the exact output I used to get with the now-deprecated EC2.client.request_spot_fleet().

My problems are:

1. It is launching a number of individual instances (in the console I see `Request type = instance`) instead of a single fleet request with that number of instances in it.
2. I have `Type="maintain"` but in the console I see `Persistence one-time`.
3. I have passed `ValidFrom` and `ValidUntil` but they are blank in the console.
4. I can't figure out how to pass it an IAM fleet role.

I have read the [boto3 create_fleet documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2/client/create_fleet.html) repeatedly.

My code is as follows:

```py
LaunchTemplateData = {
    "IamInstanceProfile": {"Arn": ecsInstanceArn},
    "BlockDeviceMappings": [
        {
            "DeviceName": "/dev/xvda",
            "Ebs": {
                "DeleteOnTermination": True,
                "VolumeType": "gp2",
                "VolumeSize": EBS_VOL_SIZE,
                "SnapshotId": SnapshotId
            }
        },
        {
            "DeviceName": "/dev/xvdcz",
            "Ebs": {
                "DeleteOnTermination": True,
                "VolumeType": "gp2"
            }
        }
    ],
    "NetworkInterfaces": [
        {
        "DeviceIndex": 0,
        "SubnetId": SubnetId,
        "DeleteOnTermination": True,
        "AssociatePublicIpAddress": True,
        "Groups": [SecurityGroup]
        }
    ],
    "ImageId": ImageId,
    "InstanceType": MACHINE_TYPE[0],
    "KeyName": KeyName,
    "UserData": userData
}

TemplateName=f'{APP_NAME}_LaunchTemplate'

try:
    launch_template = ec2client.create_launch_template_version(LaunchTemplateName=TemplateName,LaunchTemplateData=LaunchTemplateData)['LaunchTemplateVersion']
except ec2client.exceptions.ClientError:
    launch_template = ec2client.create_launch_template(LaunchTemplateName=TemplateName,LaunchTemplateData=LaunchTemplateData)['LaunchTemplate']

SpotOptions = {"AllocationStrategy": "lowestPrice"}
LaunchTemplateConfigs = [
    {
        'LaunchTemplateSpecification':
            {
                'LaunchTemplateId': launch_template['LaunchTemplateId'],
                'Version':'$Latest'
            },
        'Overrides': [
            {
                'MaxPrice':'%.2f' %MACHINE_PRICE,
                'SubnetId':SubnetId
            }
        ]
    }
]
TargetCapacitySpecification = {
    'TotalTargetCapacity':CLUSTER_MACHINES,
    'OnDemandTargetCapacity':0,
    'DefaultTargetCapacityType':'spot'
}
```

Comment: What is `CLUSTER_MACHINES` set to?

Comment: `CLUSTER_MACHINES` = 3 @JohnRotenstein